# Google Merchant Center claim & Verification issue

Tags: shopify, google-ad-manager, merchant-account, google-ads-data-hub

I have two Shopify online stores for two locations(first store for main domain and second store for sub domain). I have set up two Merchant sub-accounts to set up shopping feeds for these stores and add the merchant verification code on the shopify. However, when I try to claim and verify the second store, the first store gets unclaimed, and vice versa. Google Merchant center Says, your website is claimed & verified by other merchant account so i am unable to claim my 2nd store.

Please tell me the solution. How can I verify & claimed both of my Google Merchant accounts to run Google Shopping ads?

I have created a sub account because I have sub domain for multiple country. but when i try to claim my 2nd store google say you already verify & Claim your webiste on Merchant account.